# "I hope you will..." or "would..." – which is correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, modal-verbs, verb-usage

Which of these sentences is correct?

> I hope you would get well soon.
>
> I hope you will get will soon.

I think that the second sentence is more apt due to tense of main verb, but I've heard that the first sentence is also correct because it emphasizes the meaning and because it is used when the speaker is unsure about the person's recovery.

Comment: But the first version *doesn't* emphasize the meaning - it just comes across as awkward/incorrect because you're mixing present tense ***hope*** with ***would*** (which is the past tense of ***will***).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Idiomatically, we don't use either of those - we just say **"I hope you get well soon"** or just [**"Get well soon."**](https://www.google.com/#q=get+well+soon)

There is no need for either *will* or *would* in this context; the main verb in the sentence (*get*) functions like an imperative, and really the focus on the sentence is on the present: "*I hope*" which implies that the hoping is right now, so it doesn't make sense to use *will* or *would*.  All of these sound natural:

> I hope you get well soon.
>   I hope you find what you're looking for.
>   I hope you enjoy your food.

*Would* is either the past tense of *will* or a hypothetical form, so it makes even less sense here.